# Thumbnail plugin in combination with smarty

Tags: php, smarty, thumbnails

I'm currently using this library to generate thumbnails

http://phpthumb.gxdlabs.com/

What I want to do is, to show all images I got in a thumbnail, so they have the same size etc.
What I did was this

```
$getAllImages = glob("images/profile/" . $db->getUserID($_SESSION['username']) . "/*.*");
$options = array('resizeUp' => true, 'jpegQuality' => 80);
$arr = array();
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($getAllImages); $i++)
{
    $thumb = PhpThumbFactory::create($getAllImages[$i], $options);
    array_push($arr, $thumb);
}
$smarty->assign('images', $arr);
```

I guess the error is clear, `$thumb` is an object and cannot be used by smarty. My smarty code currenty is this

```
{foreach from=$images item=res}
<div id={$res} class="imageShow">
<a href="{$res}" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"><img src="{$res}" ></a><br>
<input type="button" name="activatePic" id="activatePic" onclick="activatePic('{$res}' , {$userid})" value="Use as profile picture">
</div>
{/foreach}
```

And this is the error message I'm getting

```
 Catchable fatal error: Object of class GdThumb could not be converted to string in F:\xampp\htdocs\FinalYear\smarty\templates_c\11edc15b4981ef4097a5734dbbaa613df53386a9.file.myPhotos.html.php on line 119
```

How can I convert or use the $thumb variable in order to fill in the array and use it in the html page in the foreach-loop?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to output the image in the middle of the html code. I don't think you can do that with this library, or even if you could, it would be a waste of resources and bandwidth. If you follow the instructions at  https://github.com/masterexploder/PHPThumb/wiki/Basic-Usage#showing-images, then your smarty code should look something like:

```
<img src="show_image.php?file={$path_and_original_image_name_here|escape:'url'}"/>
```

It's still not the best method (you probably should add restrictions, caching, more parameters...) but it's a start